# Silverlight 4.0: Chart Toolkit ItemSource

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

Im migrating my application from visifire to toolkit. I am new to charting toolkit.

How to bind chart data if the itemsource is of type PagedCollectionView?

As I've seen [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-Toolkit-Overview.aspx) the example is by using KeyValuePair. Is it just really by keyvaluepair?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would bind to the SourceCollection property on the PagedCollectionView. That way, in your XAML, you can explicitly specify the attributes on your object to bind to... That makes the XAML easier to read and easier to maintain in my opinion. For example:

```
<chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Title="Actual" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SavingsPagedViewCollectionSummary.SourceCollection}" 
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Company}" 
    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Savings}" />
```